# How can I fetch all the divs that belong to a class in html and unless they are a specific div, change their class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to implement a channel selector, currently when you select a channel it turns bold, but if you select another, the first one remains bold too. What I can't figure out is when a channel is selected, check through the divs in the selected class and if there's a div that is not the one selected then remove it from the selected class. This'll ensure only the selected channel is bold. Have attached the pertinent code snippet. Thanks.

```js
function addClass(someID){
 document.getElementById(someID).className += " selected";
  }
```

```css
.selected{
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id = "channel">Choose A Channel: <br><div class="ch">
<div id="ESPN" onclick="addClass('ESPN')">&nbsp; ESPN<br></div>
<div id="Comedy" onclick="addClass('Comedy')">&nbsp; Comedy<br></div>
<div id="Fox" onclick="addClass('Fox')">&nbsp; Fox&nbsp;News<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Learn to use the `classList` property instead of concatenating strings to `.className`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the div using the `.selected` class and simply remove it before adding the new one. With this logic you will be sure only one div is selected.

```js
function addClass(someID) {
  if(document.querySelector('.selected'))
    document.querySelector('.selected').className = "";
  document.getElementById(someID).className = " selected";
}
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="channel">Choose A Channel: <br>
  <div class="ch">
    <div id="ESPN" onclick="addClass('ESPN')">&nbsp; ESPN<br></div>
    <div id="Comedy" onclick="addClass('Comedy')">&nbsp; Comedy<br></div>
    <div id="Fox" onclick="addClass('Fox')">&nbsp; Fox&nbsp;News<br></div>
  </div>
```

By the way it's better to consider using `classList` and make your code more generic by doing something like this :

```js
function addClass(element) { /* No need to use ID as you can simply use this for the clicked element*/
  if(document.querySelector('.selected'))
    document.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove("selected");
  element.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="channel">Choose A Channel: <br>
  <div class="ch">
    <div id="ESPN" onclick="addClass(this)">&nbsp; ESPN<br></div>
    <div id="Comedy" onclick="addClass(this)">&nbsp; Comedy<br></div>
    <div id="Fox" onclick="addClass(this)">&nbsp; Fox&nbsp;News<br></div>
  </div>
```

And an easier jQuery solution :

```js
$('.ch > div').click(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="channel">Choose A Channel: <br>
  <div class="ch">
    <div id="ESPN">&nbsp; ESPN<br></div>
    <div id="Comedy">&nbsp; Comedy<br></div>
    <div id="Fox" >&nbsp; Fox&nbsp;News<br></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Assigning `className = ""` will remove unrelated classes as well. Better to use `.classList.remove("selected")`

Comment: @Barmar yes i totally agree, and it's not the only bad thing .. using onclick to is not a good idea with ID like this ... am gonna update with a complete better alternative

Comment: Works perfectly, I wasn't acquainted with the document.querySelector() method. Will read more now. Thanks.

Comment: @TheClashster i added more ways if interested ;)